# How to use MinGW make with Vim on Windows

Tags: vim, makefile, mingw

I have installed Vim and MinGW on my machine, so I try to create Hello World then compile in in Vim and everything work fine. However when I type `:make` it show error `'make' not recognized as an internal or external command`.

I already added variable path to `C:\MinGW\bin`. I want to know how to configure Vim or my machine to allow `make` command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you confirm that there is a `make.exe` in `C:\MinGW\bin`?  I seem to remember that last time I installed mingw, it was called `mingw32-make.exe`.

If there is no `make.exe` but there is a `mingw32-make.exe`, you'll have to change the `'makeprg'` option:

```
:set makeprg=mingw32-make
:make
```

Comment: Could you suggest me, where can I learn about more about vim?

Comment: There's a lot of very useful information in the documentation (`:help`): read through some of the `usr_XX.txt` files to find out all sorts of information.  There are some good hints on http://vim.wikia.com as well.  To be honest, there's so much information out there the best way to learn (assuming you've read the basics in the `usr_XX.txt` files) is to use it, work out what you're doing a lot and then try to find a better way: either by using `:helpgrep`, googling or by asking questions here on on the mailing list.  See also http://www.moolenaar.net/habits.html