# How to Compile C++ Code Using Vim on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, gcc, vim

First, I install **Vim** *(Text Editor)* in *Typical* type, on this Windows 7 laptop. And this user that I'm using is an administrator on this computer but couldn't open file in *“Program Files”* location for writing with Vim. So I change my `:cd` current directory to my `$HOME`.

*Note:* I already have installed Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop. I just want learn how to use this.

1. Can I compile C++ code using **Vim** in *Typical* type alone on Windows?
2. If it's possible, then what's the process for compiling C++ code?

I have *hello.cpp* file but I can't compile it. I already use `:comp gcc` and `:make` and the output is: *'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,*

But when I use `:comp msvc` and `:make`, the output is: *'nmake' is not recognized as an internal or external command,*

Now, what should I do? If it's not possible using Vim alone, how can I compile using Vim with the compiler on my VS Express for Desktop?

Comment: `vim` cannot compile C/C++ code by itself.  You need to have a compiler for that.

Comment: msbuild will come with vs, not make

Comment: Use `:!<CommandHere>` to execute a command in vi. I never use this feature though, I always have a separate terminal open where I do `make` from because it is much easier to read and respond to compiler output that way.

Comment: Though I approve of using vim and the command line, why not open Visual Studio and compile from there (under the build menu)?

Comment: @devnull How about *$VIMRUNTIME\compiler\gcc.vim* or else in the $VIMRUNTIME\compiler\ directory?

Comment: You need to set up your `PATH` environment variable properly for nmake to be found - it's located in one of the VS installation folders - or start vim from the "VS command line" shortcut.

Answer (score 7):

VIM is a great text editing tool,its like an awesome version of notepad.But it's not a compiler,neither has a build in compiler of itself.So In order to compile the program you'll need a separate compiler installed,like You can use MinGW.

See This :
[How to use MinGW make with Vim on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423478/how-to-use-mingw-make-with-vim-on-windows?rq=1)

Comment: If you would like to help me deeply, please read my previous comment on *Pavel K*'s answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654191/how-to-compile-c-code-using-vim-on-windows/18654627#comment27499571_18654366

Answer (score 3):

Vim is just an editor tool. To compile a program you need a *compiler tool chain*. The one that Visual Studio use is Microsoft Visual Studio C++ Compiler, so you could use it. Or install and use [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/).

The make file that you are generating is used by [make utility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_%28software%29) to actually compile the code for you. There is a Windows version of this tool.

However I would suggest you to perform *minimum* steps to compile a c++ program manually for better understanding of the process:

Create source .cpp file -> Create object file with a compiler-> create executable with a linker

Good step-by step instructions for [Visual c++ here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639.aspx)

If you prefer to use gcc, these are good links how to [install](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-MinGW-%28Minimalist-Gnu-C/C%2B%2B-Compiler%29-on-Microsoft-Windows) and [use](http://www.wikihow.com/Compile-a-C-Program-Using-the-GNU-Compiler-%28GCC%29) it on Windows.

Comment: Vim already included *$VIMRUNTIME\compiler\gcc.vim* script? So you mean, to be able to use it, I need to install **gcc**?

Comment: @Servant no - you usually use make on linux with gcc to get things to compile. Visual studio does it differently. Or, you can also install a make utility and use that. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235639.aspx for command line instructions

Comment: I thought the compiler made object files, and the linker linked them?

Comment: @PavelK Now I know how to compile a C++ program on the command line of **Developer Command Prompt for VS2012**. Now how can I compile on the command line with **Vim** and what is the purpose of the command `:comp msvc`? What is the use of a script in the */compiler* directory such as *$VIMRUNTIME\compiler\msvc.vim* script? I thought msvc means *“Microsoft Visual C++”*. And what is the use of `:make`?